# jQuery UI draggable and droppable duplicate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Hey all I am having issues with the following jQuery Draggale/droppable UI:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/sm0961st/)

It works just fine when I *first* drag the **awesome** text into the **pdfCanvas** div. Though after the first one, when you again drag the **awesome** text into the **pdfCanvas** it duplicates it twice instead of just once like it did for the first one.

Also when you try to move an **awesome** text that's inside the **pdfCanvas** it moves **all** of the **awesome** text that's currently in there.

The JS:

```
$(".resize-drag").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true,
  grid: [5, 5]
});

$("#pdfCanvas").droppable({
  accept: '.resize-drag',
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
      x = ui.helper.clone();
      ui.helper.remove();
      x.draggable({
        helper: 'original',
        cursor: 'move',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(ui.draggable).remove();
        }
      });

      x.appendTo('.resize-drag');
    }
  }
});
```

Would be great if someone see's and knows a fix on how to correct this issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so your problem is that you append your new clone to the resize-drag. Thus you contain the new objects inside the one you are cloning.

I have created a new JSFiddle for you to see it work. It needs a little tweaking to get the position right. But I hope this points you in the right direction.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm0961st/42/)

```
$("#pdfCanvas").droppable({
  accept: '.resize-drag',
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
      var clone = ui.draggable.clone(false);
      clone.css('left', ui.offset.left)
           .css('top', ui.offset.top)
           .css('position', 'absolute')
           .removeClass('ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging resize-drag')
           .addClass('dropped-element');
      $('#pdfCanvas').append(clone);
      $(clone).draggable({
        containment: 'parent'
      });
    }
  }
});

function addDraggable(){
  $(".resize-drag").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true,
  grid: [5, 5]
  });
}

addDraggable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kristian. Though I need to be able to move the **awesome** text *freely* inside the **pdfCanvas**. On you're example it's unable to move once dropped into the **pdfCanvas** area.

Comment: @StealthRT I have updated my answer and it is now working and being redraggable inside the container.

Comment: Now that works fine but it seems that every new drop is now calculated incorrectly since it keeps pushing the **awesome** text further away from where I drop it.

Comment: @StealthRT It is now working as intended. It was because of relative positioning.

Comment: @ugg... now I cant place the **resize** part of it within the code. Please check my update https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/sm0961st/36/

Answer (score 1):

Check [my trial in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hamamsy/sm0961st/27/). I think It will help you.

```
 $(".resize-drag").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  connectToSortable: "#pdfCanvas",
  revert: 'invalid',
  cursor: 'move',
  grid: [5, 5]
});

$("#pdfCanvas").sortable({
items: '.resize-drag',
connectWith: '#pdfCanvas',  

});
```

Comment: This is a sortable table. I need it to be movable throughout the inside of the **pdfCanvas**.